# What do input min and max actually do?

Tags: html, html-input

I was expecting `min` and `max` for `<input>` to limit the selectable options to the range in between the two values. They do in `<input type="number">`, for example. But with `type="datetime-local"` they don't. As far as I can tell, they don't actually do much of *anything*?

```html
<label for="select_start">Without min/max</label>
<input type="datetime-local" id="select_start">

<label for="select_end">With min/max</label>
<input type="datetime-local" id="select_end" min="2023/5/9" max="2023/6/8">
```

Both are exactly the same, so far as I can tell (viewing them on Google Chrome in 2023).

*Do* `min` and `max` actually do anything? And what *can* I do to limit the selectable options to the desired range?

Answer (score 0):

You understood correctly that you can narrow down the range of the input value using the `min` and `max` attributes. You just provided the date in the wrong format. Since you created a "datetime-local" type input field, the minimum and maximum values need to be in the standard ISO 8601 format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm`, such as `1970-01-01T23:59`.

##### Example

```js
// Just show value of range
const value = document.querySelector("#rangeValue")
const input = document.querySelector("#rangeInput")
value.textContent = input. Value
input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  value.textContent = event.target.value
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="number">number</label>
    <input type="number" name="" min="1000" max="2000">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="range">range</label>
    <input type="range" name="range" id="rangeInput" min="-4" max="10" step="2">
    <output id="rangeValue"></output>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date">date</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" min="2023-05-09" max="2023-06-08">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="time">time</label>
    <input type="time" name="time" min="12:00" max="14:00">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="datetime-local">datetime-local</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime-local" min="2023-05-09T00:00" max="2023-06-08T00:00">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="week">week</label>
    <input type="week" name="week" min="2023-W12" max="2023-W14">
  </div>

  <input style="display: none;" name="disable-form" required>

  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

#### More information

- [Global Date(Time) Formats for HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#examples) - MDN Docs
- [Attributes for <input type="number">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#validation) - MDN Docs
- [Attributes for <input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#validation) - MDN Docs
- [Attributes for <input type="datetime-local">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#validation) - MDN Docs

#### Warning

> **As a general rule, don't trust anything that users enter into forms.** Filling out forms online is complicated and tedious, and it is easy for users to enter wrong data or data in the wrong format. In addition, malicious folks are well-versed in the art of entering specific strings of executable code into form fields (for example, SQL or JavaScript). If you're not careful about handling these types of inputs, it could either execute harmful code on your site or delete your databases. See [SQL injection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Website_security#sql_injection) for a good example of how this could happen.
>
> Read more: [Sanitize form input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security#sanitize_form_input)
> by MDN Docs

Comment: What are you quoting from with the last blockquote?

Comment: @Laurel, I think this didn't want to be a quote, just formatting, nevertheless, you are right! I will correct it because it's misleading! I wrote it. **To make it more credible, I looked up the official alert for my "sanitize form input" warning in the MDN Docs!** This way, it is indeed more acceptable!

Answer (score -1):

The min and max attributes do not work with datetime-local input types. These are generally used with date or numeric input.
Restricting selectable options to a certain range using the datetime-local type requires the use of a custom validation approach in JavaScript.

Comment: The minimum and maximum value options are also available for date fields! [MDN - HTML/Element/input/datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#validation)